# Laravel Forge Deployment Fails

Tags: laravel-forge

I've recently signed up to Laravel Forge and Digital Ocean. The server setup was simple enough but when I went to deploy a repository, it failed.

```
Cloning into 'admin.domain.testing.co.uk'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '104.192.123.2' to the list of known hosts.
/home/forge/.forge/provision-48336658.sh: line 29: composer: command not found
```

Does anyone know what this means or where I can find out more information on what went wrong?

regards

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I have several server there, but I encountered this error on the last one.

Comment: yes, dont know why but yet my ssh keys work on everything else, forge or digital ocean dint seem to like them! `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"` no passphrase then copy them (`pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) and add to forge